# Using Joi schema to get a json object with fields specified in the schema

Tags: node.js, joi

I am not sure if this type of question has been asked before, but I was not able to find anything related to this. In my current project we use Joi schemas to perform the validations. I like the ability to define custom schemas and run validations on the incoming objects using that schema. I have a task where I need to filter out object properties. Something similar to `_.pick` but the properties are complex and deal with nested objets and arrays. We already have a joi schemas that we have designed to perform validations but I am thinking of using the same to get the specific properties of the object, like filtering object data using that schema. Something like this:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const val = {
  a: 'test-val1',
  b: 'test-val2'
}
const schema = Joi.object({
   a: Joi.string()
});
// now the below result have the object with both `a` and `b`
// properties but I want joi to strip the `b` property from the object
const result = schema.validate(value, { allowUnknown: true });
```

Joi's documentation doesn't mention anything like this. I have come across [this(ajv)](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv#filtering-data) library which does do what I want but I wanted to know for sure if this can not be achieved using `Joi`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the docs, don't you have to add the `removeAdditional` flag to remove properties not specified by the joi schema?

Comment: @KevinFriedheim That for the `ajv` library and not Joi. I wanted to know if Joi offers something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Joi offers `stripUnkown` property that can be used to get only the fields defined in the schema.